# EWS SearchFilter is not working with some email adresses when using FindItems on a folder

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

The following code below returns zero items.

```
EWSService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
            EWSService.TraceListener = tr;
            EWSService.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.DebugMessage | TraceFlags.EwsRequest | TraceFlags.EwsResponse;
            EWSService.TraceEnabled = true;
            EWSService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(user, psw,domain);
            EWSService.Url = new Uri("https://----/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

FolderId id = Test(EWSService, "inbox", null);

Folder source = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder.Bind(EWSService, id);

SearchFilter> slist = new List<SearchFilter> ();

Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.From, "some@emailaddress.com"));

SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, slist);

ItemView messageView = new ItemView(99);
FindItemsResults<Item> list = source.FindItems(filter,messageView);
```

the list sometimes contains 0 items when I use a specific email address in the searchFilter even when the mail item is present in the folder.

When I don't use a SearchFilter with FindItems it is present in the list.

How come the SearchFilter is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

First off.

You DONT need a List of Searchfilter, if you only want to look for ONE email address

```
SearchFilter> slist = new List<SearchFilter> ();
```

Now on to some recommendations:

1. I'd recommend using a query string instead of a `SearchFilter`.

   ```
    // Find all items where the From: contains "some@emailaddress.com".
     string filter= "From:\"some@emailaddress.com\"";
   ```

   Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn579420(v=exchg.150).aspx
2. Do not pull 99 items in the ItemView instead pull 20 and use pagination

   ```
   ItemView messageView = new ItemView(20, 0, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning);
   ```
3. Load only the properties that you NEED

   ```
   messageView.PropertySet = BasePropertySet.IdOnly;
   ```
4. Define how deep do you want to search

   ```
   messageView.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow
   ```

The code below is ONLY an example of how I've used the findItems method in the past for my own projects using VB... FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES

```
Private Function GetAllSyncedContactIdsInExchange(pService As ExchangeService) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim oInternalContactIdDefinition As New ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, conContactIdPropertyName, MapiPropertyType.Integer)
    Dim oInternalContactIdFilter As New SearchFilter.Exists(oInternalContactIdDefinition)
    Dim oResults As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = Nothing
    Dim oPropertySet As New PropertySet(oInternalContactIdDefinition)
    Dim lstSyncedContactIds As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim intDBId As Integer
    Dim lstEESContactFolders As List(Of FolderId) = GetAllCustomEESFolderIds(pService)

    For Each oFolderId As FolderId In lstEESContactFolders
        Dim blnMoreAvailable As Boolean = True
        Dim intSearchOffset As Integer = 0
        Dim oView As New ItemView(conMaxChangesReturned, intSearchOffset, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning)
        oView.PropertySet = BasePropertySet.IdOnly

        Do While blnMoreAvailable
            oResults = pService.FindItems(oFolderId, oInternalContactIdFilter, oView)
            blnMoreAvailable = oResults.MoreAvailable
            If Not IsNothing(oResults) AndAlso oResults.Items.Count > 0 Then
                pService.LoadPropertiesForItems(oResults, oPropertySet)
                For Each oExchangeItem As Item In oResults.Items
                    If oExchangeItem.TryGetProperty(oInternalContactIdDefinition, intDB2Id) Then
                        lstSyncedContactIds.Add(intDBId)
                    End If
                Next
                If blnMoreAvailable Then oView.Offset = oView.Offset + conMaxChangesReturned
            End If
        Loop
    Next

    Return lstSyncedContactIds
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My code above is adapted code from a project. The search filter list is required because in my project there is the possibility of multiple items. I'll try out your suggestion and post my outcome.

Comment: I tried your answer using a querystring (containing up to 10,20, ... email addresses) but the execution time to FindItems is for some mailboxes 3 to 4 minutes. Each time a new FindItems is executed it takes a lot of time.